# Read in csv file in python, round the values and write back to file

Tags: python

I have a csv file with lines like this:

```
x;y
232,6209718;109,5003569
..
```

I would like to read them in replace the , with a . and round the values.
I know how to read in csv and round(x), but don't know how to combine and loop through 2 values and round them.

Thanks..

Comment: Show us what you have tried and then we'll talk about how to fix it

Comment: If you know how to do most of it, then post the code for that and we can help with the remainder. Break down the problem into it's constituent parts, ask questions about *just* the parts that you can't get to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did it without your help:

```
import csv

with open('input.csv', 'rU') as inf:
    x = []
    y = []
    for line in csv.reader(inf):
        tx , ty = line
        x.append(float(tx))
        y.append(float(ty))


xround = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in x ]
yround = [ '%.2f' % elem for elem in x ]

print xround
print yround

rows = zip(xround,yround)

with open('rounded.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Answer (score -2):

assuming you readlines into content variable ..

```
for line in content:
line = line.split(";")
    for item in line:
        item.replace(",", ".")
        write to file here ...
```

Comment: Firstly, this does not round the values. Secondly, it's best practices to use default `csv` module. Last, but not least, python comments start with `#`.

Comment: They need to round the values as per the post

Comment: You really should use the `csv` module here, you are not rounding, and you are not writing out the result again.